# How to run a background process in PHP and read/write its stdout/stdin?

Tags: php, background-process

As an extension to question "[php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)":

Suppose I wanted to keep a process running during a PHP session, like an interactive `bash` shell.  How can I establish redirection of stdout/stdin such that PHP can read/write to the process?

UPDATE: The key is to be able to kick off the process and keep it running in the background so that later requests can access its stdout/stdin streams.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [PHP Expect](http://php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php). The documentation has some very good [usage examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/expect.examples-usage.php).

Comment: Once the process is started, how do you get its handle back on successive requests?

Comment: @spoulson: Ah, I see - your question is clearer now you've updated it :-). That's much harder, let me think...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux, you can access the proc file system at /proc. Though distributions may differ somewhat, in Ubuntu Server I can find my stdio at /proc/<pid>/fd/[012]. 0 is stdin, 1 is stdout, and 2 is stderr. This will probably not work if you are redirecting these from or to /dev/null, as some methods of spinning off long running background processes have you do. If you have access to the pid of the background process (a la http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2007/01/12/running-a-background-process-in-php/), you should be able to access the stdin / stdout of the process in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP to relay user-typed commands to a shell, you can use mulitple calls to [shell_exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

shell_exec will return the complete output which you can then echo back to the user.